# Is my plan to use Alexa to turn on a fireplace reasonable?

Tags: switch, data-wiring

I have a fireplace (gas) with a constant 0.5V low voltage current as the igniter connected to a single pole switch.  I would like to add Alexa via a 120VAC separate smart switch that has a timer that will be set for 2 hours.  I plan to retain the current low voltage switch as a "seasonal switch" in the circuit that will keep the low voltage side inactive except during the short winter when it is active.

The setup: There is a 3 way switch just above the low voltage switch, and has 120VAC in a red wire common when tested to ground.  The switch currently powers nothing that I have been able to find and cannot find a second three way connected to it anywhere.  I plan to replace the current three way with the smart switch (requires a neutral plus two wires) and use the currently hot red wire to power the smart switch (120V), and the hot wire plus ?pigtail from neutral white to power a 120V-5V transformer that then activates a relay for the low voltage circuit for the ignition.

Is this a viable setup?  Should I just cap the black wire travelers to the current 3 way switch?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: I would never empower an IoT device to start a fire.

Comment: How are you making sure you had ignition and are not just letting gas out?

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box?

Comment: you don't want to mess with the three-way switch until you find the other one.

Comment: The other three way must have been disconnected since I have checked all other switches.  The house has a combination of Lutron Maestro, older Leviton SPST switches, Lutron Caseta, and Leviton DHC R10 switches.  Clearly some of the older switches have been replaced, and with some of the Lutron switches, travelers are not needed in a 3 way and I assume they were capped off somewhere behind one of the newer switches.   Turns out the red was not hot- it was black, but on closer inspection was white wrapped in black electrical tape.  Go figure.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You've edited your question into a "Thanks" message, losing the original text. This isn't how this site works; please  [take another look at our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: What happens when alexa gets angry with you and starts a fire on her own?   "Open the pod bay doors HAL", "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that"

Comment: I hear the song Daisy, Daisy in the background playing....

Comment: @SolarMike that was the most reasonable statement here! I have never thought about it. This would require a battery backuped temperature sensor and a batter backuped wifi plus a sensor that sends an alarm when the power is gone. And having all of that would still not be full proof because these days all of these need internet alive which can be gone if a squirrel rides an external electrical box...
So this idea of saying "alexa turn on fire place" seems to be put into garbage...